# Disable link generation to translation of pages which have no translation - TYPO3 9

Tags: php, typo3, translation, typolink

I have a website where only a part should be translated (into english - german is default). But on this page also links to pages with only a default language version are displayed in menus.
These links to non translated pages should not get the base slug of the active translation. Is this somehow possible?

---

Example:

I have to Pages (A and B). Page **"A"** has only a version in the default language (german). **"B"** has versions in german and english.
If page **"B"** is rendered in english, links to page **"A"** will have the base slug for this language (f.i. "en"). But this will result in a 404 or a "english page" with german text.

I already tried to use the language fallback config for languages, but that seems to have no effect on link builders.

Comment: Why do you set links in page "B" in english to page "A" which is not in english? Don't do it and your problem is gone? Or did I missed something?

Comment: But I have to. Only a part of the website is translated, but the rest should still be reachable for visitors.

Comment: Do both pages have there own Site Configuration? What are they look like?

Comment: @TobiasGaertner what exactly do you mean with „Site Configuration“. They are both children of the same Root Page.

Comment: With "Site Configuration" I mean what you see under the BE Module "Sites" and what results in a yaml-config file. So you "Root Page" contains that?

Comment: This is the language part of the yml-confi file:
`languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    languageId: '1'
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_GB.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: gb`